# Program bypass first fgets

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

The problem is when it asks the user to enter the name of the band.The program bypass the first fgets, but executes the printf and not the fgets. I tried to handle this problem with if but again the same problem. Bypass the first fgets. I provide you an image also.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct cd
{
   char band[100];
};

struct cd *music;

int main()
{
  int n,i;
  printf("Give how many albums you want: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  struct cd *music = malloc(sizeof(struct cd)*n);

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {

    printf("\nEnter Band: ");
    fgets(music->band,sizeof(music->band),stdin);
    music++;
   }

  for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    music--;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
    printf("\nBand: %s",music->band);
    music++;
   }

  printf("\n\n");
  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is due to a queued up `\n` after `scanf` (`scanf` reads the number, leaves the newline, newline gets picked up by `fgets`).

Comment: Thanks for showing me where was the problem.

Comment: Do not mix `scanf()` with `fgets()`.  Best to use the `fgets()/sscanf()` combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you read with scanf() it reads everything leaving the following '\n' from the end
And Now when you try to read with fgets()it reads the'\n' character left by scanf

To solve this you can use fgetc(stdin); after your scanf so that it gets consume.

Comment: That won't work if you happen to type, say, an extra space after the number. To skip to the end of the line, either call `fgets()` and ignore the result, or write an explicit loop that calls `fgetc(stdin)` until it returns either `'\n'` or `EOF` (the loop works regardless of the length of the input line). Or just do `fgets()` in the first place and use `sscanf()` to parse the line.

Answer (score 4):

Scanf() treats '\n' as a character and since it is not in the format string, it leaves it there.

try this

```
char newline;
int n,i;
printf("Give how many albums you want: ");
scanf("%d%c",&n,&newline);
```

This will remove the '\n' from the stdin.

Comment: Consider: `"*c"` avoids the need for `newline`.